# Two-column macro in PlainTeX

Tags: pdftex, columns, plain-tex

While reading the TeXbook, I became curious to make my own double-column macro. I have tried to split content with \vsplit and boxes, but I have had no success thus far. Using a LaTeX package is a viable option too, but in my case the purpose of the macro is to learn the low-level components, not for some specific project.

I'm not a TeXnician yet, so any example of some kind of \doublecolumn macro (not output routine) would be really appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your `(not output routine)` comment as two-column code is all about the output routine

Comment: eplain supports double columns: https://tug.org/eplain/doc/eplain.html#Multiple-columns

Comment: [`doublecol`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/doublecol) on CTAN is perhaps what you're looking for

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Don Knuth, in the TeXbook, wrote that it is also possible to create double columns with \vsplit and boxes, that is what I meant:)

Comment: but that implies manual page breaking do you also want manual column breaking

Answer (score 3):

These are the basics for quick column breaking:

```
\newdimen\gutter \gutter = 5mm % space between the columns
\long\def \doublecolumn #1{{%
    % set the material with a reduced hsize
    \setbox0 = \vbox{\hsize = \dimexpr (\hsize - \gutter) / 2 \break #1}
    % set topskip on first column (a trick; uses the \break above)
    \splittopskip=\baselineskip
    \setbox4 = \vsplit0 to 0pt
    % split the column (add baselineskip/2 to encourage the first column
    % to be larger than the second when the number of lines is odd)
    \setbox2 = \vsplit0 to \dimexpr (\ht0 + \baselineskip) / 2
    % set the columns (uses vtop for alignment on first baseline)
    \hbox to\hsize{\vtop{\unvbox2}\hss\vtop{\unvbox0}}}}

\doublecolumn { lorem ipsum etc ... }
```

For more general-purpose column breaking, you will need the output routine for adding to the to-be-columnated list incrementally, using `\pagegoal` and `\pagetotal` for determining how much material to split off on each page. The `eplain` macroes do this, as noted above, and they are a good place to start for learning more on this subject.

Comment: That's fine. I've tried to use `eplain` with `optex` because eplain allows footnotes in columns -- it _almost_ works, except for a weird error message that is literally _printed_ on the page, instead of the terminal.